# Using Many-To-Many junction table in another relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a question about Hibernate ManyToMany mappings. I have two classes A and B and the mapping between them is a ManyToMany mapping resolved by Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="A_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_id"))
    private Set Bs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="b")
    private Set As;
}
```

The foreign keys to User and Group are "A_id" and "B_id". Join Table is called A_B.

Now, I would like to add C. I would like A_B has a relation with C, creating an Many-To-Many Relationship with C and A_B that I can call A_B_C.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="C")
public class C {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="C_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="?????"))
    private Set A_Bs; // Don't have any UserGroup entity !
}
```

**EDIT :** So I will create A_B entity, with 2 @OneToMany Relationship for A and B and A_B.

**Question :** What's the best solution for A_B about primary key ? Embedded Primary Key or Generated Id ? I don't want to have duplicate (user_id, group_id) :/ Only Unique constraint is enough ?

What about A_B <-> C relationship ? Don't need any entity A_B_C I guess, and @ManyToMany would be enough...

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want to have a relation to UserGroup then create a UserGroup entity (and have 1-N User-UserGroup, and 1-N Group-UserGroup). You cannot bastardise a join table used for some other relation

Comment: So adding UserGroup (A_B now) entity, I can make @ManyToMany relationship with C, but on A_B, I need generated Id or EmbeddedId ?

Comment: you need an Id on any entity. Whether that is an Id formed from User.id and Group.id (with IdClass) or EmbeddedId (with those 2 fields), or whether you want a separate Id just for those objects it is up to you.

Comment: Let's say I add a generated id on my A_B entity. How to be sure I don't have duplicated in the functionnal point of you ? (Id 1, User A to Group A, Id 2, User A to Group A)

Comment: you can do unique constraints ...

Comment: It's what I will do. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need an association to `User` in `Group`, because of `Group` is a something like dictionary.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_groups")
    private Set<Group> groups;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

}
```

And you need a `@ManyToMany` association to `Group` in `Newsletter`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="newsletters")
public class Newsletter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="newsletters_groups")
    private Set<Group> groups;
}
```

Comment: Well, I knew I would have called my table A, B and C, my example is bad... But from functional point of view, you're right, it's better ;)